# Access file from different domain in Java

Tags: java, grails, file-io

I have to access a file on the same network but in a different domain. I keep getting an access denied error when I try to download the file to my server (Java IO file not found). It's a PDF file I am trying to display to the user. My co-workers said it says that because it is "password protected but this is not true ftp."

Here is how I have tried with no results:

```
file://USERNAME:PASSWORD@172.16.1.8/reports/Orders/backup/RA0035_001_20110314_1.pdf
```

They said the domain name is SBC, so i've tried.
             file://SBC/USERNAME:PASSWORD@172.16.1.8/reports/Orders/backup/RA0035_001_20110314_1.pdf

I'll just throw this in here, but this is how I am getting the file. This is in Grials.

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(fullLocation);
render(file:  is , contentType: 'application/pdf')
```

Comment: What protocol is the server that's hosting the file using? It's hard to tell based on your description, but it looks like CIFS (Windows File Sharing) or FTP are both possibilities. Whatever the case, you need to use a library that speaks that protocol. You can't just pass a URL like that to FileInputStream.

Comment: Its using windows file sharing

Comment: http://jcifs.samba.org/

Comment: @JohnR I recommend posting this as an answer instead of a comment to make it clearer (free internet points)